# PHP variable won't show inside form input

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm able to insert info into other fields in the form, but the contactnumber will not. There is data for it in the database. When the page loads the field is just blank. If I remove the (array) from the line giving the error I get
*Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line 27* which is this line I commented below in the php file. It was working and stopped. Not sure why. Please help. Thanks.

***form input where I want to display the contactnumber***

```
<p>
 <input type="text" name="contactnumber" id="contactnumber" value="<?php echo 
 $string_contactnumber; ?>" readonly>
</p>
```

***query that selects the contactnumber from adminlogin where adminlogin.profileid = coin.profileid***

```
<?php       
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","administrator_logins");

        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['profileid'] != 'profileid') {

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT adminlogin.contactnumber FROM adminlogin INNER JOIN coin ON coin.contactnumber=adminlogin.contactnumber WHERE adminlogin.profileid=coin.profileid") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $contactnumber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);


        //this is the line of code that is giving the error
        $string_contactnumber = implode(',', $contactnumber);

        mysqli_close($con);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that. Though, do you know why my variable wont show in the input field?

Comment: This should give you the contact number: $string_contactnumber = $contactnumber['contactnumber'];

Comment: @Johanne you're my hero. Stay golden champ.

Comment: @Johanne You should put that as an answer.

Comment: @Dharman thanks will do.

Comment: @AspiringCoderLuke  you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the contact number:

```
$string_contactnumber = $contactnumber['contactnumber'];
```